# How to remove white background on selecting options in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a select box for selecting Gender and its on black background. When I select an option in IE, it is adding a white backgroud as shown below :

[image]

I have added the following style rule to remove this color, but it is not working.

```
select:focus::-ms-value {
    background-color: #111118;
}
```

I don't need any backgroud color here and it should appear like the following image :

[image]

Not sure why it is happening only on IE. How this can be fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

Tried the following styles and it worked fine

```
select {
    background-color: #000;
    border: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    color: grey;
  }

  select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
  }

select:focus::-ms-value {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

see in [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WQB5YGjIT3p9XVCGunbv?p=preview)

Look in your source for conflicting styles.